# Find contacts with given display name

Tags: android, contacts

Learning Android I'm trying to find contacts using DISPLAY_NAME selector. I need to find all contacts with given name. Everything goes great using standard query, but falls when I use ContentProviderOperation. I do not understand some of features. When debugging i see exception: Empty values. But, which values I must insert there? Thanks.

```
    op.add(ContentProviderOperation.newAssertQuery(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI)
      .withSelection(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " = '" + name + "'", new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts._ID})
      .build());        
    try {
        result = getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, op);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

Comment: can you post the stacktrace of the exceptions?

Comment: 10-08 19:15:05.786: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(223): Uncaught handler:thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
10-08 19:15:05.796: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(223): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty values
10-08 19:15:05.796: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(223): at android.content.ContentProviderOperation$Builder.build(ContentProviderOperation.java:412)

Comment: Can you edit your post and paste the _entire_ stacktrace in as a codeblock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is with your second line of code which should read:

```
.withSelection(
    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " = ?",
    new String[] {name}
)
```

To explain, the withSelection method takes two parameters, the selection string and an array selectionArgs, these are substituted into the selection string during query compilation.  So in this example the `?` is subtituted for the value of `name`. Text qualifiers (single quotes) are automatically embedded at the same time so no additional effort is required

Comment: Thanks. I've noticed my mistake. I've change my code to `  op.add(ContentProviderOperation.newAssertQuery(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI)
    .withSelection(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + "=?", new String[] {name}).build());` But there is same exception :( But... with withExpectedCount(1) and it works, but when I try to get result[0].uri it throws nullPointerException.

Comment: @SergeyIvonchik please do not post code into comments. Add an update to your question by writing **UPDATE** so others can see what stage you are at. Do not alter the origincal question, just add more information.  Also upvote answers that are helpful.

Comment: this operation will not return a uri, please use `result[0].count` instead.  If the answer resolves your problem please boost my rep by accepting the answer as correct ;)